# Index an array as leading keywords

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like the following:

```js
[
    'Main interaction point of this Map.',
    '@param {*} Key',
    '@param {*} Val',
    '@returns {Map}'
]
```

I'd like to index it starting with a `description` tag, and then index the following parameters from `@param`, `@returns`, etc. The output should be something like this:

```js
{
    description: "Main iteration point of this Map.",
    param: [
        "{*} Key",
        "{*} Val"
    ],
    returns: "{Map}"
}
```

But, when I have leading no-tags, the last tag should apply:

```js
[
    'Sorts all the elements in the Map and returns it.',
    '@param {Function} [cfn] Specifies a function that defines the sort order.',
    'If omitted, the Collection is sorted according to each character\'s Unicode point value,',
    'according to the string conversion of each element.',
    '@param {*} [thisv] Value to use as `this` when executing functions.',
    '@returns {Map}'
]
```

This should return:

```js
{
    description: "Sorts all the elements in the Map and returns it.",
    param: [
        "{Function} [cfn] Specifies a function that defines the sort order. If omitted, the Collection is sorted according to each character's Unicode point value, according to the string conversion of each element.",
        "{*} [thisv] Value to use as `this` when executing functions."
    ],
    returns: "{Map}"
}
```

Notice how the lines without a tag aren't a new param? I haven't figured out how to do this, could anybody give an example? Thanks

Comment: How are you currently parsing the other tags? Could you should us what you've written so far?

Comment: It's a very simple switch statement that gets the first word and indexes that into an object (and if there's no tag, it's the description tag), nothing too special about it. I haven't figured out how to do trailing tags, so the lines without a tag will be joined into the previous one

Comment: You should provide your code in your question, preferrably within a runnable snippet.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest keeping a state/status variable `keyword` with the last tag seen, defaulting to `"description"`. Then you would use recognizable tags like `"@param"` to update the status, and use the status to correctly write the rest of the line to your object.

```js
// pseudocode
let output = {};
let keyword = "description";
for (const line of lines) {
  // search for "@" at beginning, followed by a keyword, followed by a space and more content
  const match = line.match(/^@(param|returns) (.*)$/); 
  let content;
  if (match) {
    keyword = match[1]; // "param" or "returns"
    content = match[2]; // content is text following the tag
  } else {
    content = line; // content is the whole line
  }
  switch (keyword) {
    // your logic
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
const result = {
  description: "",
  param: [],
  returns: ""
};

let last_tag = "";
for(text of test) {
  switch(true) {
    case text.startsWith("@param"):
      last_tag = "@param";
      result.param.push(text.replace("@param", "").trim());
      break;
    case text.startsWith("@returns"):
      last_tag = "@returns";
      result.returns += text.replace("@returns", "").trim();
      break;
    default:
      switch(last_tag) {
        case "@param":
          result.param[result.param.length -1] += text;
          break;
        case "@returns":
          result.returns += text;
          break;
        default:
          result.description += text;
      }
      result.description = text;
  }
}
```